# Push down automata problem

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Informally describe the Nondeterministic PDA that generates:

$$\{x\#y\ \mid x,y\in\{a,b\}^{*}\text{and}\space x\ne y\}$$

My initial plan was to use nondeterminism to go through each character before and after the # and try to match them, and if they do not match, then accept. So I would check the first char against the first char after #, etc. However I can't get this idea to work since I can't seem to both record the character position after the # as well as the character I need to match against before the # with the single stack.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to convert CFGs to PDAs?

Comment: No I do not but if its not too much trouble I can definitely try to learn to solve this.

Comment: It's not important, though it is perhaps easier to construct a CFG for the language than a PDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following languages:
$$\newcommand{\A}{\mathtt{a}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathtt{b}}
\newcommand{\P}{\mathtt{\#}}\begin{gather}
L_\text{long} = \{ x \P y : x , y \in \{ \A , \B \}^* , | x | > | y | \};\\
L_\text{short} = \{ x \P y : x , y \in \{ \A , \B \}^* , | x | < | y | \};\\
L_\text{diff} = \{ x \P y : x , y \in \{ \A , \B \}^* , | x | = | y |, ( \exists k ) ( x_k \neq y_k ) \}.
\end{gather}$$
Note that your language $L$ is clearly the union of these three languages, and so a nondeterministic PDA for $L$ can first nondeterministically choose which of these three languages the string belongs to, and then check that the string actually belongs to that language.  (Nondeterministic) PDAs for $L_\text{long}$ and $L_\text{short}$ are relatively easy to construct, the real difficulty is with $L_\text{diff}$.

I don't claim that $L_\text{diff}$ is context-free (I actually don't think it is), but there is a context-free language which includes $L_\text{diff}$ as a sub-language, and is itself a sub-language of $L$: let $L^\prime_{\text{diff}}$ consist of all strings $w \in \{ \A , \B , \P \}^*$ such that

- $\P$ occurs exactly once in $w$; and
- if $w^\prime$ is the string obtained by removing the single instance of $\P$ in $w$, then $w^\prime \in \{ xy \in \{ \A , \B \}^* : |x| = |y| , x \neq y \}$.

It should be clear that $L_\text{diff}$ is a sub-language of $L_\text{diff}^\prime$, and every string in $L_\text{diff}^\prime$ belongs to $L$.

Suppose that $x = x_1 \cdots x_n$ and $y = y_1 \cdots y_n$ are such that $x \neq y$.  This means that there is an $k \leq n$ such that $x_k \neq y_k$: for the moment let us suppose $x_k = \A$ and $y_k = \B$.  Then we may rewrite our string as $$x y = x_1 \cdots x_{k-1} \;\A\; x_{k+1} \cdots x_n \; y_1 \cdots y_{k-1} \;\B\; y_{k+1} \cdots y_n$$  Note that the substring $x_{k+1} \cdots x_n \; y_1 \cdots y_{k-1}$ has length $(n-k) + (k - 1 ) = n - 1$ and so let us write it as $$z_1 \cdots z_{k-1} z_k \cdots z_{n-1}$$  Then 
$$\begin{align}
xy &= x_1 \cdots x_{k-1} \;\A\; x_{k+1} \cdots x_n \; y_1 \cdots y_{k-1} \;\B\; y_{k+1} \cdots y_n \\ 
&= \overbrace{x_1 \cdots x_{k-1}}^{\text{length } k-1}\; \A\;\overbrace{z_1 \cdots z_{k-1}}^{\text{length } k-1} \; \overbrace{z_k \cdots z_{n-1}}^{\text{length }n-k} \;\B\; \overbrace{y_{k+1} \cdots y_n}^{\text{length }n-k}
\end{align}$$
So the string $xy$ can be seen as the concatenation of two odd length strings $u , w$ which have different middle symbols.  Once this is observed, it is relatively easy to construct a nondeterministic PDA for this language.  (First non-deterministically decide whether the first substring has a $\A$ as its middle symbol and the second a $\B$, or *vice versa*, as you read the string first pop a symbol onto the stack until you non-deterministically guess the middle symbol of the first substring, and then pop those symbols off; once the stake is empty again pop symbols back on and non-deterministically guess where the middle symbol of the second string is.)

To obtain a nondeterministic PDA for $L_\text{diff}^\prime$ also ensure that you find one (and only one) $\P$ in the string before accepting (but reading a $\P$ does not affect the stack in any way).

Comment: I think there is something wrong, e.g. $\{\mathtt{a},\mathtt{b}\}^* \notin \mathtt{a}^i$ (maybe you put $\mathtt{a}^i$ on intention, but then please explain why).

Comment: @dtldarek: The reason I did it that way was because I _completely and utterly_ misread the question.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @dtldarek: The language $\{xy:x,y\in\{\mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \}^*, |x| = |y|, x \neq y \}$ is context-free.  A CFG for it (using the observations above) is $S \to AB \mid BA$; $A \to aAa \mid aAb \mid bAa \mid bAb \mid a$; $B \to aBa \mid aBb \mid bBa \mid bBb \mid b$.  Changing a PDA for this language to $L_\text{diff}^\prime$ is essentially doubling up the states into "haven't found it yet" and "found it already" pairs (for finding the single $\mathtt{\#}$), and accepting only in "found it already" states.  (Also reading a $\mathtt{\#}$ in a "found it already" state results in rejection.)

Comment: Ok, now it was my turn to misread ;-) Of course it is a CFL!

Comment: I believe you construction for $L_{\text{diff}}$ is enough, if you just drop in a $\#$ anywhere in the middle part. If it turns out not to be the precise center, no harm done; if it is, ensuring that the $a$ is paired with $b$ or viceversa is all that is required. Your other two cases cover "symmetric strings" with  $\#$ off-center.

Comment: @vonbrand: I'm not sure if I am understanding your comment correctly.  (I also assume you are talking about my $L_{\text{diff}}^\prime$ and not the almost certainly non-CFL $L_\text{diff}$.)  It is easy to show that $L_{\text{diff}}^\prime \subsetneq L$, as it does not contain strings like $\mathtt{aa\# bbb}$ (because it is of even length) and $\mathtt{aaa\# aaaaa}$ (since $L_\text{diff}^\prime$ ignores the exact placement of the $\mathtt{\#}$).

Answer (score 3):

This is actually easier than Arthur Fischer is making it.  We can make more use of that $\#$ marking the middle of the string.  My answer is actually much along the lines of what you said you tried, I think.  I guess you might have been forgetting that you're allowed more than one state, which does make it a bit easier to construct the automaton.

Call your language $L$ and let $X = \{a,b\}$.  Let $L_1 = \{u\# w \mid u,w\in X^*, |u|\neq |w|\}$ and let $L_2$ be the language of all strings $u\# w$ with $u,w\in X^*$ and $u_i\neq w_i$ for some $i\leq \min\{|u|, |w|\}$.  Then your language is the (non-disjoint) union of $L_1$ and $L_2$.  (I'm using $|u|$ for the length of $u$.)

Recognising $L_1$ with a pushdown automaton is very easy.  To recognise $L_2$, have in addition to the start state $q_0$ five states $p_a$, $p_b$, $q_a$, $q_b$ and $q$, the last being the only accept state.  Use a single stack symbol $X$.  In $q_0$, we put an $X$ on the stack every time we read a symbol.  If we read $\#$ in $q_0$, the automaton should fail, since $q_0$ is for reading the word $u$ in $u\# w$.  At any point, we can non-deterministically guess that we have reached the point at which $u_i\neq w_i$.  In this case, move to state $p_x$, where $x$ is the symbol just read.  At this point we have $i-1$ $X$'s on the stack.

In the state $p_x$, we read without modifying the stack or changing state until we read a $\#$, at which point we move to the state $q_x$.  Here, we pop an $X$ off the stack for each symbol read.  When the stack is empty, the automaton fails unless the next symbol read is not $x$, in which case it moves to $q$ and accepts.

(Note, the way I have described this shows that $X$ could equally well be any finite alphabet.  Also, it's possible to use less states if you prefer.)

Comment: Yikes!  Boy my answer was convoluted as all heck!

Comment: It was understandable, since the more common version of this is without the $\#$, so you just adapted the (more complicated) idea usually used for that.

Comment: I wanted to write this answer on the day the question was posted, but just didn't have time until now.

Comment: Actually, I think I just have a tendency to do things the complicated way.  (But, yes, thinking about the non-$\#$ version didn't help matters; I guess [this bad joke](http://jokelabs.com/humor_jokes-det-171-mathematician_wants_to_become_firemen.html) might not be too far off.)